# Android Button ==> Set highlighted image?

Tags: android, button, background-image, highlight, selected

How can i set  the button to show a different image after it's been tapped?
Either a different image, or maybe some kind of highlighting that shows the button was tapped/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a ImageButton on your layout you can set different images for different states: normal, selected and pressed; using a state drawable, defined in xml, like this (`btn_state.xml`, under res/drawable directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" />
    </selector>
```

Of course, you need those btn_normal, selected and pressed as PNGs in your drawables directory.

On your `<ImageButton>` then you set that resource name as the background:

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/btn_state"
    ... />
```